# How to align button with text box that has label in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to align button to text box?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/action" method="get">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <label for="from_date">From date</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="from_date" name="from_date" type="text">
        <p class="help-block">* Dates are inclusive</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <label for="to_date">To date</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="to_date" name="to_date" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">        
        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Go">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding a padding to your last div is one solution.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 toppadding">        
    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Go">
  </div>
```

in css class add

```
.toppadding
{
    padding-top:23px;
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6834/)

Comment: It's the same my temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are what's throwing it off, you can use the solution above or get rid of labels altogether by using placeholders:

```
<input class="form-control" name="to_date" type="text" placeholder="To Date">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6y88u1ts/

Comment: We need labels in this example.